# Android: How to increase button click response speed?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a clock application for Android. I managed to implement the stopwatch feature, but it still seems to be full of problems.

The response is too slow, i.e. when I click the start button the response is slow, so it doesn't start immediately. This is the same when clicking the stop button.

Is it not enough with the currently provided methods? or is there a better alternative for the solution? Please help me.

```
public class StopWatchView extends LinearLayout{

    private int tenMSecs = 0;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private TimerTask timerTask = null;
    private TimerTask showTimeTask = null;

    private TextView tvHour, tvMinute, tvSecond, tvMSecond;
    private Button btnSWStart, btnSWResume, btnSWReset, btnSWPause, btnSWRecord;
    private ListView lvWatchTimeList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private static final int MSG_WHAT_SHOW_TIME = 1;

    public StopWatchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public StopWatchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public StopWatchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate(){
        super.onFinishInflate();

        tvHour = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHour);
        tvHour.setText("0");
        tvMinute = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMinute);
        tvMinute.setText("0");
        tvSecond = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSecond);
        tvSecond.setText("0");
        tvMSecond = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMSceond);
        tvMSecond.setText("0");

        btnSWRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSWRecord);
        btnSWRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.insert(String.format("%d:%d:%d.%d",
                        tenMSecs/100/60/60,
                        tenMSecs/100/60%60,
                        tenMSecs/100%60,
                        tenMSecs%100),
                        0);
            }
        });

        btnSWPause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSWPause);
        btnSWPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopTimer();

                btnSWPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSWResume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSWReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSWRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        btnSWReset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSWReset);
        btnSWReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopTimer();
                tenMSecs = 0;
                adapter.clear();

                btnSWStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSWPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSWReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSWRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSWResume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        btnSWResume = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSWResume);
        btnSWResume.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTimer();

                btnSWResume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSWReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSWRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSWPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        btnSWStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSWStart);
        btnSWStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTimer();

                btnSWStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSWPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSWRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        btnSWRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSWPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSWReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSWResume.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        lvWatchTimeList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvWatchTimeList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lvWatchTimeList.setAdapter(adapter);

        showTimeTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_WHAT_SHOW_TIME);
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(showTimeTask,200,200);
    }

    private void startTimer(){
        if(timerTask == null){
            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tenMSecs++;
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(timerTask,10,10);
        }
    }

    private void stopTimer(){
        if(timerTask != null){
            timerTask.cancel();
            timerTask = null;
        }
    }

    public void onDestory(){
        timer.cancel();
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            switch (msg.what){
                case MSG_WHAT_SHOW_TIME:
                    tvHour.setText(tenMSecs/100/60/60+"");
                    tvMinute.setText(tenMSecs/100/60%60+"");
                    tvSecond.setText(tenMSecs/100%60+"");
                    tvMSecond.setText(tenMSecs%100+"");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: You can implement touch event for the button. And when got touch event, you can do your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button placed in a Scrollable parent, it will cause delayed response. Try non-scrollable container or override OnTouchListener

```
   button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                button.setPressed(true);
            }
            return onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this, if you are using `com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat`, then you can increase the ripple speed to increase the click response speed, for example:

```
button.rippleSpeed *= 12 // or some other number of similar magnitude
```